# Varnish and PHP session validation

Tags: php, session, cookies, varnish

I run a largely session-dependent site in front of which I want to put **Varnish**.

The user *might* get a Set-Cookie header on the first request, it depends on which URL he entered.

PHP's `session_start` is used.

How can I make sure that the Cookie header from a client is in fact related to a valid PHP session if Varnish is in front?

If there is no Cookie header sent from the client I can easily send it to the backend for a `Set-Cookie`.

Right now I use an AJAX request which returns a Set-Cookie header for each page, that is supposed to (in)validate the Cookie for a user, and it seems for work for 95% of the visitors. The missing 5% is causing a lot of headache.

Is there a widely used method for solving this?

Comment: How exactly do you plan on leveraging Varnish if most of the requests contain a `Cookie` header that will be used while the rest will get a `Set-Cookie` response header? Both these headers cause Varnish to not cache the response.

Comment: A custom vcl_recv makes it possible to ignore that default behavior. I realized i have two scenarios: paywall behavior with signed cookies, or having Varnish make session validation requests to a backend. The first gives very high performance but can leave the user with an incorrect session until timeout in case the session storage has been cleared. The second gives exact session knowledge to varnish but adds a few ms to each request (redis connection or so), and ideally i don't think this should be handled by Varnish. PHP's session storage idea really makes it hard to scale an app